# Hosting Blazor WebAssembly Progressive Web App in virtual directory under the Subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-pwa

I have two virtual directories under a subdomain: one hosts a Blazor WebAssembly Progressive Web App, while the other hosts an ASP.NET Core application. The Blazor WebAssembly PWA is not running as expected within its virtual directory, whereas the ASP.NET Core app is functioning correctly.

when I copy the same files of  Blazor WebAssembly Progressive Web App in the subdomain it runs correctly. what should I do?[image: this is the pic of how i am creating virtual dictionary]

the following is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What are you using to serve your files? Apache. Nginx. etc... How do you currently have it configured? (actual config files, not a vague explanation.) You haven't really given enough information for anyone to help you. Is you Blazor WASM app being served from the root of the subdomain? It sounds like we need to compare your virtual directory configs if it works in one and not the other.

Comment: I have edited my question I think now clear to understand. By the way, I am publishing on IIS.